# Habitable Antarcticas

Tags: earth-like, climate

I'm curious about a couple of scenarios involving a habitable or partially-habitable Antarctica. I'm not all that concerned about how to get there from present-day Earth, though it might be interesting to discuss; I'm much more interested in what it would look like given these particular scenarios.

Couple things in advance:

- I'm assuming that not much else changes about Earth, except things caused ultimately by the temperature increase alone. This is meant basically as an extreme global warming scenario, and most other things (continental movements, intentional human terraforming, etc) are slower or more fantastical than I'm interested in.
- I'm aware of Antarctica's subglacial topography, and I know there would be a lot less land area without the glaciers. I also know that isostatic rebound is a thing, but I'm mostly disregarding that for this purpose - it's too slow.
- I'm aware of the Antarctic Circumpolar Current, and I know that thanks to that, it would take a very large temperature increase in the rest of the world to make Antarctica even approach habitabilty. (I am curious just how much, though.)

The first scenario would extend habitability (which I guess could be defined as 'temperatures high enough to allow forestation') to around 80 degrees south - inland a bit, but not to the actual centre. The second would extend habitability all the way to the centre.

I'm curious primarily about the temperature gradations across latitudes, and how different the interior would be from the coast. If the coast was habitable, I imagine the centre would still be a frozen wasteland, but how far would that extend? If the centre was habitable, how hot would the coasts get?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We always advise one question per post otherwise questions are closed as too broad. Maybe you could ask a series of questions to with one question per post.

Comment: This all seems to me like one overarching question, and splitting it up into sub-questions seems like you'd have to cross-reference between the questions too much to make it easy. How would you divide it?

Comment: I would first ask only your last question (about how hot the world is) as this fuels all the others, Once you have that you can ask second and third questiosn which summarise the information here as well as whatever answer you got to part 1. In those you should ask about winds (and possibly temperature gradients) and in the other you ask about habitability and the day night cycle. Finally you ask about Bouvet and the Keguelens whilst giving as much information about the wind, temperature and vegetation as you have.

Comment: If you need help with the questions, or just someone to check them over, we have a sandbox for questions: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: @Sjiveru As a rule bonus questions are a bad idea and should be deleted. As per the [help/on-topic] questions on this site should be specific and answerable. You can [edit] your question to make it a better fit for this site.

Comment: Bonus question was deleted. I guess I'm not understanding what a 'single question' is - should I just reformulate this to ask 'what would Antarctica be like under these conditions', and then focus on specific outworkings of that? I don't really want to start with the whole-world temperature, as it's the part of this that interests me the least.

Comment: Maybe I confused you by phrasing it as a list of 'questions' rather than a list of specific subtopics to one question? (Would such a rephrase still somehow fail the 'specific and answerable' test?)

Comment: Going off wikipedia, the average temperature on the coast is -10C and in the coldest parts of the interior is -55C. Warming the world by 10C would probably still make most of it completely uninhabitable. 10C warming would be an extinction event across the whole planet.

Comment: As I said, I would remove all questions but the last one for this post and only start asking the other parts in subsequent questions.

Comment: Edited to hopefully be more targeted to a specific aspect of the question. (Breaking up a question into subparts and asking them all separately seems very, very odd to me; but if that's y'all's policy, I guess I have no choice.)

Comment: @Sjiveru now it seems good to me.

Comment: A good question that needs refining. I think the problem is that you are asking a question without specifying enough detail for anyone to be able to answer it without using guess work. It would depend on how different the conditions were. What scenarios are you allowing? Movement of continents? Space based solar arrays? Redirecting of currents? Changes in earth’s orbit or axial tilt? Magic even?

Comment: @Slarty Fair enough! I assumed 'no other changes' didn't need mentioning, but I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: Can I petition to get this reopened now? How does that work?

Comment: Yes I think it might need a little extra. If there's no change then we have what we currently have. If there's some change then what are we allowed to change?

Comment: It works by voting. I can have a look, but it will need another 4 or 5 users with sufficien reputation as well